# Como faço para executar o Cron Jobs no PHP?

Tags: php, agendamento, cron

Eu queria usar o Cron Jobs nesses php:
titulos.php

```
<tr>
<td bgcolor="<?=$highlight?>">


<?
require('config.php');
$sqle = "SELECT * FROM tb_ads WHERE user='$last' and ident='$id'";
$resulte = mysql_query($sqle);        
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($resulte);
mysql_close($con);


$time=$myrow['visitime'];

$crok1 = date(time());
$crok2 = date($time + (24 * 60 * 60));



if($crok1 >= $crok2)

{ 

?><?=$bold?><a href="view.php?ad=<?=$id?>" target="_blank"><?=$description?></a><?=$boldc?><?



 } else { ?><del><?=$description?><del><? }


?>


</td>
<tD bgcolor="<?=$highlight?>">
<?=$members?>       

</td>
<td bgcolor="<?=$highlight?>">

<?=$outside?>

</td>
<td bgcolor="<?=$highlight?>">

<?=$total?>

</td>
</tr>
```

titulosp.php

```
<tr>
<td bgcolor="<?=$highlight?>">


<?
require('config.php');
$sqle = "SELECT * FROM tb_ads WHERE user='$last' and ident='$id'";
$resulte = mysql_query($sqle);        
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($resulte);
mysql_close($con);


$time=$myrow['visitime'];

$crok1 = date(time());
$crok2 = date($time + (24 * 60 * 60));



if($crok1 >= $crok2)

{ 

?><?=$bold?><a href="viewp.php?ad=<?=$id?>" target="_blank"><?=$description?></a><?=$boldc?><?



 } else { ?><del><?=$description?><del><? }


?>



</td>
<td bgcolor="<?=$highlight?>">
<?=$members?>       
</td>
<td bgcolor="<?=$highlight?>">
<?=$outside?>
</td>
<td bgcolor="<?=$highlight?>">
<?=$total?>
</td>
</tr>
```

Eu to usando um script PTC que ele Reinicia os anuncios do site depois de 24 Horas mais eu queria quer resetasem as 23h 59, Pra quem não sabe oque PTC pesquisa no Google, Obs já criei a Cron Jobs no CPanel:

```
59 23 * * * php -f /home/u844214382/cronjobs
```

Answer (score 5):

Falta por o nome do arquivo que você deseja que o php abra:

```
59 23 * * * php -f /home/u844214382/cronjobs/nomedoarquivo.php
# -------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```