# Enviar e-mail automaticamente em PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, envio-de-email

Tenho um website onde possui de uma base de dados, e na mesma base de dados, à uma parte onde possui umas datas, algumas delas que ainda irão acontecer.
O que pretendia é que quando chegasse a cada data de cada linha da Base de Dados, fosse enviado um email para todos os utilizadores registados no website.

O que eu gostava de saber, era como fazer este email de forma automática. Chegando a esse dia, e fosse enviado os emails.

Trabalho com PHP e Mysql. Alguma ajuda sobre isto?

Comment: vc precisa agendar o seu .php no cron(linux) ou no agendador de tarefas(windows). http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12793/como-faco-para-executar-o-cron-jobs-no-php

Comment: [Como agendar uma tarefa recorrente no linux](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2818/como-agendar-uma-tarefa-recorrente-no-linux)

Comment: @perdeu devias por isso como resposta para que todos possam saber como se faz. E para evitar respostas repetidas.

Comment: Poderia especificar qual SO (Linux ou Windows) você utiliza? Se for Linux creio que sua pergunta é duplicata dos links que o @perdeu mostrou.

Answer (score 3):

Supondo que você esteja usando Linux: agende uma tarefa diária no `cron`. Faça com que essa tarefa diária rode um script PHP que conecta ao seu bancos e execute a tarefa desejada – nesse caso, enviar os emails.