# PHPMailer - Reenvio de e-mails é possível?

Tags: php, phpmailer

Existe alguma implementação que possa ser feita no `PHPMailer` pra que e-mails que não conseguiram ser enviados (devido à queda momentânea do servidor do site que utiliza do `PHPMailer`, por exemplo) possam ser enviados depois?

Pode ser alguma espécie de monitoramento do servidor do e-mail ou registro de e-mails a serem enviados (conferir se foram enviados ou não).

Answer (score 3):

O que podes fazer aqui é criar uma tabela na base de dados com os emails que não foram enviados e por um [cron](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12793/como-fa%C3%A7o-para-executar-o-cron-jobs-no-php) a correr de hora a hora por exemplo, ou o intervalo que pretenderes a tentar reenviar os emails que ficaram pendentes.

Answer (score 0):

O método `Send()` da classe retorna um Booleano que será `false` se a mensagem não for enviada por qualquer motivo.

```
<?php
require("class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'smtpusername';
$mail->Password = 'smtppassword';

$mail->AddAddress("email@exemplo.com");
$mail->Subject = "assunto";
$mail->Body = "PHPMailer.";

if(!$mail->Send())
{
   echo "Erro: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else
{
   echo "E-mail enviado";
}
?>
```

Pode usar um Loop infinito para ficar tentando enviar, porem isto não é uma boa prática pois a aplicação pode ficar presa nisso tentando enviar sem sucesso, logo utilizei um `for` limitando o numero de tentativas a 10, cada tentativa esta espaçada em 30 segundos.

```
for($tentativas = 0; $tentativas < 10; $tentativas++){
    if($mail->Send())
    {
       break;
    }
    sleep(30);
}
```

Comment: ricardo isso não é muito boa ideia... Ficava a aplicação presa nisso até que ele conseguisse enviar. O melhor seria ter um cron a correr de x em x tempo a tentar enviar e-mails pendentes.

Comment: @JorgeB. ele pode limitar o numero de tentativas, vou adicionar isso agora

Comment: ricardo mas isso não resolve nada. Se o servidor estiver em baixo a probabilidade de todas falharem é enorme.

Comment: @JorgeB. O que seria "o servidor estiver em baixo"?

Comment: @ricardo Esse loop de tentativas eu já vi em outras fontes e ajuda bastante. A questão maior ficaria em relação a quando o servidor cair (isso que o JorgeB. deve querer dizer com 'servidor em baixo'. Aí teriam e-mails pendentes cujas tentativas de envio fracassaram. Mesmo assim, obrigado pelas respostas.